# Finding control points for bezier curve

Tags: actionscript-3, math, bezier

Hi stackoverflow's users !

First i want to say its my first post and i've been diging straight up gold from this site and i love it and everyone out there smart enough to give out solutions.

So basically am writing a game and i have bezier curve that controls where an actor moves. Am using only 3 points (start, control1, end) and everything is fine.

Now i want to create a bezier curve that passes through a certain point (r1) at t = 0.5 . The problem being that i have my start point, my end point and my point (r1) at t=0.5, and i need to find the control point.

Sorry if i explained it badly i hope everyone can understand.

Thank you for any replies : )

Comment: is r1 is the mid-point (or the crest) between the start and end points of the curve?

Comment: A bezier curve needs two control points. Have you merge your points together? Or do you have some other simplification?

Comment: @ja72:  ActionScript3's drawing API currently only supports bezier curves with one control point.  "real" bezier curves with 2 control points is coming in Flash Player 11.

Comment: @ja72:  of course, that's only if you're using the drawing API and not rolling your own curves.

Comment: yes, r1 is the midpoint, you can use from 2 to n points for bezier curves if am correct

Answer (score 3):

Look into the documentation of `Asymptote` ([here](http://asymptote.sourceforge.net/doc/Bezier-curves.html#Bezier-curves)) which has a geometrical interpretation of the a spline. For the mid point (t=-.5) the point lies in the point m_5 below. If you are using one control point them c_0 and c_1 are coincident simplifying the math. If at (t=0.5) your y values is `y_c` and the beginning and ending values are respectively `z_0` and `z_1` then the control point is at

```
c = (8*y_c-z_0-z_1)/6
```

Do the same for the `x` values.

[image]

Comment: i understand what you are saying but i cannot figure out the 8 and 6 in that equation, where did you get those ?! :/

Comment: from `y = z_0 (1-t)^3 + c_0 * 3*(1-t)^2*t + c_1 * 3*(1-t)*t^2 + z_1*t^3` with `c = c_0 = c_1` and `y(t=0.5)=y_c`.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the question I asked a couple of days ago: [Given f(x) linear function, how to obtain a Quadratic Bezier control point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17253816/given-fx-linear-function-how-to-obtain-a-quadratic-bezier-control-point). I think it's exactly what you need.