# Given f(x) linear function, how to obtain a Quadratic Bezier control point

Tags: math, language-agnostic, uibezierpath, bezier

I've been doing a lot of research on the topic and found a couple of post that where helpful but I just can't get this right.

I am developing a very simple structural analysis app. In this app I need to display a graph showing the internal stress of the beam. The graph is obtained by the formula:

```
y = (100 * X / 2) * (L - X)
```

where `L` is the known length of the beam (lets say its 1 for simplicity). And `X` is a value between 0 and the Length of be beam. So the final formula would be:

```
y = (100 * X / 2) * (1 - x) where  0 < X < 1.
```

Assuming my start and end points are `P0 = (0,0)` and `P2 = (1,0)`. How can I obtain `P2` (control point)?? I have been searching in the Wikipedia page but I am unsure how to obtain the control point from the quadratic bezier curve formula:

```
B(t) = (1 - t)^2 * P0 + 2*(1 - t)*t * P1 + t^2 * P2
```

I'm sure it must be such an easy problem to fix… Can anyone help me out?

P.S.: I also found this, [How to find the mathematical function defining a bezier curve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1853637/how-to-find-the-mathematical-function-defining-a-bezier-curve), which seems to explain how to do the opposite of what I am trying to achieve. I just can't figure out how to turn it around.

Comment: If you haven't, you may want to take a look at Math.SE http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks! I already looked into the maths section. I just don't know what to do with the "t" value. I tried doing the same as the question I linked but the "t" remains, so I'm left with a useless coordinate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We want the quadratic curve defined by `y` to match the quadratic Bezier curve
defined by `B(t)`.

Among the many points that must match is the peak which occurs at `x =
0.5`. When `x = 0.5`,

```
y = (100 * x / 2) * (1 - x)

    100     1      25
y = ---- * ---  = ---- = 12.5
     4      2       2
```

Therefore, let's arrange for `B(0.5) = (0.5, 12.5)`:

```
B(t) = (1-t)^2*(0,0) + 2*(1-t)*t*(Px, Py) + t^2*(1,0)
(0.5, 12.5) = B(0.5) = (0,0) + 2*(0.5)*(0.5)*(Px, Py) + (0.25)*(1,0)

0.5 = 0.5 * Px + 0.25
12.5 = 0.5 * Py
```

Solving for `Px` and `Py`, we get

```
(Px, Py) = (0.5, 25)
```

And here is visual confirmation (in Python) that we've found the right point:

```
# test.py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)
y = (100*x/2)*(1-x)
t = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)
P0 = np.array([0,0])
P1 = np.array([0.5,25])
P2 = np.array([1,0])
B = ((1-t)**2)[:,np.newaxis]*P0 + 2*((1-t)*t)[:,np.newaxis]*P1 + (t**2)[:,np.newaxis]*P2
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.plot(B[:,0], B[:,1])
plt.show()
```

Running `python test.py`, we see the two curves overlap:

[image]

---

*How did I know to choose `t = 0.5` as the parameter value when `B(t)` reaches its maximum height?*

Well, it was mainly based on intuition, but here is a more formal way to prove it:

The y-component of `B'(t)` equals 0 when `B(t)` reaches its maximum height. So, taking the derivative of `B(t)`, we see

```
0 = 2*(1-2t)*Py
t = 0.5 or Py = 0
```

If Py = 0 then B(t) is a horizontal line from (0,0) to (1,0). Rejecting this degenerate case, we see `B(t)` reaches its maximum height when `t = 0.5`.

Comment: Wow! Thank you very much unutbu. That was easy… So let me get this straight, reading your code I conclude that the maximum point of the bezier occurs at t = 0.5. Is this ALWAYS the case?

Comment: @t0t3m: It was just a lucky guess. But I've added above a more formal argument why `t=0.5` is the right choice.

Comment: I edited the control point math with the changes @Teeppeem pointed out. I think I got it right but feel free to check it out. The graph for visual confirmation is still the same one.

Answer (score 2):

Your quadratic bezier curve formula has a typo in the middle term.  It should be:
`B(t) = (1 - t)^2 * P0 + 2 * (1 - t) * t * P1 + t^2 * P2`
This means you should take the `P1=(1,50)` that @unutbu found and divide the coordinates in half to get `P1=(.5,25)`.  (This won't matter if you're plotting the parametric equation on your own, but if you want something like LaTeX's `\qbezier(0,0)(.5,25)(1,0)`, then you'll need the corrected point.)

The `P1` control point is defined so that the tangent lines at `P0` and `P2` intersect at `P1`.  Which means that if `(P1)x=(P2)x`, the graph should be vertical on its righthand side (which you don't want).

In response to your comment, if you have a quadratic `y=f(x)`, then it is symmetrical about its axis (almost tautologically).  So the maximum/minimum will occur at the average of the roots (as well as the control point).

Comment: I was actually going to ask that right now. The new control point (0.5, 25) makes a lot more sense tan the previous (1,50). I already corrected the formula. Thanks!